# Map Across an Array of Strings to Generate 'Select' Options (React/Node)

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have these two select bars:

[image]

When I select an option from the first bar, I have it set up to populate this object like so:

[image]

I am trying to make it so that the options available in the **second** select bar populated as the **contents of the `needed_skills` array.**

So in this example, the options in the second select bar would be: "Proposal Writing", "The McKinsey 7s Framework" etc

My attempt was this:

```
  const createInputs = () => {
    return values.skills_required.map((skill, idx) => {
      return (
        <div className="input-group">
            <select 
                  value={skill} placeholder="Enter a skill" 
                  onChange={e => updateSkill(e, idx)} 
                  className="form-control">
                  <option>Select an option...</option>
                        {values.category2.needed_skills && values.category2.needed_skills.map((c, i) => (
                          <option 
                                key = {i}
                                value={JSON.stringify(c)}>
                                {JSON.stringify(c)}
                            </option>
                               ))}
               </select>
              <div className="input-group-append">
                  <button 
                        className="btn btn-outline-danger mb-3" 
                        type="button" 
                        id="button-addon2" 
                        onClick={() => removeSkill(idx)}>x
                   </button>
              </div>
        </div>
      );
    });
  };
```

But nothing, even though when I `console.log(values.category2.needed_skills)` and get the array, I cant seem to map across it and return it as options in the 'select' dropdown.

Any advice/help is greatly appreciated.

@malfunction is correct, when I console log the index and elements of the loop I get nothing. How can I loop through this array of strings? My data structure is exactly like this:

```
const [values, setValues] = useState({
    name: '',
    description: '',
    pitch_price: '',
    categories: [],
    category: '',
    quantity: '',
    applications: '',
    business_name: '',
    skills_required: [''],
    category2: {
      name: "",
      needed_skills: [""]
    },
    photo: '',
    created_by: '',
    loading: false,
    error: '',
    createdProject: '',
    redirectToProfile: false
  });
```

The `category2` part is where I am keeping the data. Also, I know that the data is actually there because when I console log my `values.category2` object after selecting a `Category` - I get this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding a return. i.e.

```
return  <option key = {i}
                    value={JSON.stringify(c)}>
                    {JSON.stringify(c)}
</option>
```

Also, not sure if `JSON.stringify` is required there. It's probably not hurting though.

Ok, that wasn't it ^^^

Without knowing the structure of your data I got this working in a new create-react-app without really changing your code:

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import { jsxFragment } from '@babel/types';


const values = {
  skills_required: [
    "skill_1",
    "skill_2"
],
  category2: {
    needed_skills: [ "Proposal Writing",  "The McKinsey Framwork", "etc"],
    some_other_stuff: {},
    a_date: "2019-09-30"
  }
}

const updateSkill = (e, idx) => {

  console.log("e: ", e);
  console.log("e: ", idx);
}

const removeSkill = (idx) => {
  console.log("e: ", idx);
}

const createInputs = () => {
  return values.skills_required.map((skill, idx) => {
    return (
      <div className="input-group">
          <select 
                value={skill} placeholder="Enter a skill" 
                onChange={e => updateSkill(e, idx)} 
                className="form-control">
                <option>Select an option...</option>
                      {values.category2.needed_skills && values.category2.needed_skills.map((c, i) => (
                        <option 
                              key = {i}
                              value={JSON.stringify(c)}>
                              {JSON.stringify(c)}
                          </option>
                             ))}
             </select>
            <div className="input-group-append">
                <button 
                      className="btn btn-outline-danger mb-3" 
                      type="button" 
                      id="button-addon2" 
                      onClick={() => removeSkill(idx)}>x
                 </button>
            </div>
      </div>
    );
  });
};


function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>

        <jsxFragment>
          { createInputs()}
        </jsxFragment>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Is your data structure similar to that? I'd say that the issue might be with the data structure possibly looping through and getting nothing.

If you're not sure you can always add a console.log in here:

```
<option>Select an option...</option>
{ values.category2.needed_skills 
&& values.category2.needed_skills.map((c, i) => {
    console.log("c", c);
    console.log("i", i);
    return ( <option 
                key = {i}
                value={JSON.stringify(c)}>
                {JSON.stringify(c)}
         </option>)
    }
  )
}
```

The initial return didn't work because the curly braces weren't there.

The only other thing I can think of is making your array it's own variable. i.e. `let needed_skills = values.category2.needed_skills;`

I hope one of those things helps.

Comment: I hadnt thought of that but no unfortunately that returns a compiler error (with parens and without)

Comment: I also got some silent warnings from React for casing on my variables. Maybe try using PascalCase for your `values` variable.

Comment: Thank you I have added a response in the edit to my post

Comment: One more thought, does `category2` change based on your previous selection? If that's the case then you need to change `category2` to `[aVariable]` so it picks up the correct part of the data structure related to your selection. (Sorry for the replies down here, I can't comment on your question yet because I'm a noob).